# How can I ensure that changing one person's health status in Salesforce Contact Tracing reflects in their cohabitants' and neighbours'?

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud

[Contact Tracing challenge in Salesforce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPSbT.png)

Code in CTPersonController :
`

> public static Set getExcludedIds(List<People_Tracing__c> peopleTracingList) {
> Set excludedIds = new Set();
> for (People_Tracing__c tracing : peopleTracingList) {
> excludedIds.add(tracing.Person_1__c);
> excludedIds.add(tracing.Person_2__c);
> }
> return excludedIds;
> }
> public static Set markCohabitantsAsOrange(List<People_Tracing__c> peopleTracingList) {
> Set excludedIds = getExcludedIds(peopleTracingList);
> Set cohabitantIds = new Set();
>
> for (People_Tracing__c tracing : peopleTracingList) {
> if (!excludedIds.contains(tracing.Person_1__c)) {
> cohabitantIds.add(tracing.Person_1__c);
> }
> if (!excludedIds.contains(tracing.Person_2__c)) {
> cohabitantIds.add(tracing.Person_2__c);
> }
> }
>
> List<Person__c> cohabitants = [
> SELECT Id, Name, Health_Status__c
> FROM Person__c
> WHERE Id IN :cohabitantIds
> AND Health_Status__c NOT IN ('Red', 'Orange')
> ];
>
> List<Person__c> personsToUpdate = new List<Person__c>();
> for (Person__c cohabitant : cohabitants) {
> cohabitant.Health_Status__c = 'Orange';
> System.debug('Updated Health Status of Person ' + cohabitant.Name + ' to Orange');
> personsToUpdate.add(cohabitant);
> }
>
> if (!personsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
> update personsToUpdate;
> }
>
> return new Set(cohabitantIds);
> }
>
> public static Set markNeighborsAsYellow(List<People_Tracing__c> peopleTracingList) {
> Set excludedIds = getExcludedIds(peopleTracingList);
> Set neighborIds = new Set();
>
> for (People_Tracing__c tracing : peopleTracingList) {
> if (!excludedIds.contains(tracing.Person_1__c)) {
> neighborIds.add(tracing.Person_1__c);
> }
> if (!excludedIds.contains(tracing.Person_2__c)) {
> neighborIds.add(tracing.Person_2__c);
> }
> }
>
> List<Person__c> neighbors = [
> SELECT Id, Name, Health_Status__c
> FROM Person__c
> WHERE Id IN :neighborIds
> AND Health_Status__c NOT IN ('Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow')
> ];
>
> List<Person__c> personsToUpdate = new List<Person__c>();
> for (Person__c neighbor : neighbors) {
> neighbor.Health_Status__c = 'Yellow';
> System.debug('Updated Health Status of Person ' + neighbor.Name + ' to Yellow');
> personsToUpdate.add(neighbor);
> }
>
> if (!personsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
> update personsToUpdate;
> }
>
> return new Set(neighborIds);
> }
>
> public static Set markPrimaryContactsAsOrange(List<People_Tracing__c> peopleTracingList) {
> Set excludedIds = getExcludedIds(peopleTracingList);
> Set person1Ids = new Set();
> Set person2Ids = new Set();
>
> for (People_Tracing__c tracing : peopleTracingList) {
> if (!excludedIds.contains(tracing.Person_1__c)) {
> person1Ids.add(tracing.Person_1__c);
> }
> if (!excludedIds.contains(tracing.Person_2__c)) {
> person2Ids.add(tracing.Person_2__c);
> }
> }
>
> List<Person__c> personsToUpdate = new List<Person__c>();
>
> List<Person__c> primaryContacts = [
> SELECT Id, Name, Health_Status__c
> FROM Person__c
> WHERE (Id IN :person1Ids OR Id IN :person2Ids)
> AND Health_Status__c NOT IN ('Red', 'Orange')
> ];
>
> for (Person__c primaryContact : primaryContacts) {
> primaryContact.Health_Status__c = 'Orange';
> System.debug('Updated Health Status of Person ' + primaryContact.Name + ' to Orange');
> personsToUpdate.add(primaryContact);
> }
>
> if (!personsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
> update personsToUpdate;
> }
>
> return new Set(person1Ids);
> }
>
> public static Set markSecondaryContactsAsYellow(Set primaryContactIds) {
> Set excludedIds = new Set();
> excludedIds.addAll(primaryContactIds);
>
> List<Person__c> secondaryContacts = [
> SELECT Id, Name, Health_Status__c
> FROM Person__c
> WHERE Id NOT IN :excludedIds
> AND Health_Status__c NOT IN ('Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow')
> ];
>
> List<Person__c> personsToUpdate = new List<Person__c>();
> for (Person__c secondaryContact : secondaryContacts) {
> secondaryContact.Health_Status__c = 'Yellow';
> System.debug('Updated Health Status of Person ' + secondaryContact.Name + ' to Yellow');
> personsToUpdate.add(secondaryContact);
> }
>
> if (!personsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
> update personsToUpdate;
> }
>
> return new Set();
> }
>
> Code in CTLocationController:
>
> public static void updateRedScore(Set locationIds) {
> List<Location__c> locationsToUpdate = [
> SELECT Id, Red_Score__c
> FROM Location__c
> WHERE Id IN :locationIds
> ];
>
> for (Location__c location : locationsToUpdate) {
> AggregateResult[] redPeoplePerLocation = [
> SELECT COUNT(Id) total
> FROM Location_Tracing__c
> WHERE Person__r.Health_Status__c = 'Red'
> AND Visit_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:10
> AND Location__c = :location.Id
> ];
>
> Integer redScore = 0;
> if (redPeoplePerLocation.size() > 0) {
> redScore = Integer.valueOf(redPeoplePerLocation[0].get('total'));
> }
>
> Update the red score and status based on the calculated value
> location.Red_Score__c = redScore;
> location.Status__c = getStatus(redScore);
> }
>
> Perform the update of the Location__c records
> update locationsToUpdate;
> }
> public static String getStatus(Integer redScore){
> if(redScore == 0){
> return 'Green';
> else if(redScore <= 5){
> return 'Yellow';
> else if(redScore <= 10){
> return 'Orange';
> else{
> return 'Red';
> }
> }
>
> Code in PersonTriggerHandler class:
>
> public static void handlePersonTracing(List<People_Tracing__c> peopleTracingList) {
> Set redStatus = new Set();
>
> for (People_Tracing__c tracing : peopleTracingList) {
> redStatus.add(tracing.Person_1__c);
> redStatus.add(tracing.Person_2__c);
> }
>
> Set orangeStatus = new Set();
> Set yellowStatus = new Set();
>
> orangeStatus.addAll(CTPersonController.markCohabitantsAsOrange(peopleTracingList));
> Set primaryContacts = CTPersonController.markPrimaryContactsAsOrange(peopleTracingList);
> orangeStatus.addAll(primaryContacts);
> yellowStatus.addAll(CTPersonController.markNeighborsAsYellow(peopleTracingList));
> yellowStatus.addAll(CTPersonController.markSecondaryContactsAsYellow(primaryContacts));
>
> List<Person__c> personToUpdate = new List<Person__c>();
>
> for (Id pid : orangeStatus) {
> personToUpdate.add(new Person__c(Id = pid, Health_Status__c = 'Orange'));
> }
>
> for (Id pid : yellowStatus) {
> personToUpdate.add(new Person__c(Id = pid, Health_Status__c = 'Yellow'));
> }
>
> if (!personToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
> update personToUpdate;
> }
>
> List<Location_Tracing__c> locationTraces = CTLocationTracingController.getLocationsByPersonIds(redStatus);
>
> if (locationTraces != null && !locationTraces.isEmpty()) {
> Set locationIds = new Set();
>
> for (Location_Tracing__c trace : locationTraces) {
> locationIds.add(trace.Location__c);
> }
>
> CTLocationController.updateRedScore(locationIds);
> }
> }`

Expecting : to change health status as per the requiremnts, code gets executed but the health status as an example when changed from Red to Green , other users health status doesnt changes at all. code is running properly but the requirements are not met as health status of others, neighbours or cohabitants remains the same.

Comment: Please format your code as a code and not as blockquotes. It is very hard to read it as it is now.